# I am using the summ() function from the jtools package with kableExtra to knit a PDF document. Why is the output being split and how do I stop it?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I am using RStudio 1.3.1093 with R 4.0.2 and I have created a markdown file for a class project. I am using the summ() function from jtools along with kableExtra to make the output from summ() look good. But when I knit the document, the table is split by a paragraph that is supposed to follow it:

[image: Picture of incorrect output]

I don't have any extra kable styling or anything, my code is simply:

```
Pfit <- lm(epa ~ yards_gained + yards_after_catch + air_yards + as.factor(fumble) + as.factor(fumble_lost) + yardline_100 + ydstogo + ydsnet, data = Pdf)

summ(Pfit)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or is my only option to remove kableExtra?